# global name 'RegisterForm' is not defined

Tags: python, django

I got a error that 
NameError at /accounts/regist/
global name 'RegisterForm' is not defined .

I did defined 'RegisterForm'.
I wrote in forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        __init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'


class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        __init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
        self.fields['password'].widget.attrs['classF'] = 'form-control'
```

in views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST



def index(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/index.html', context)


@login_required
def profile(request):
    context = {
        'user': request.user,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile.html', context)


def regist(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/regist.html', context)


@require_POST
def regist_save(request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('main:index')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/regist.html', context)
```

in urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login/$', login,
        {'template_name': 'registration/accounts/login.html'},
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^regist/$', views.regist,name='regist'),
    url(r'^regist_save/$', views.regist_save, name='regist_save'),
]
```

How can i fix it?
Furthermore,I really cannot understand i did not write global anywhere.(I am a beginner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined it in forms.py, but you didn't import it into views.py.

Note also, your `__init__` methods will not work; that is not how you call superclass methods. You need to use the `super` method:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and similarly for LoginForm.

Comment: thx ur comments.by the way,where should i write ur class RegisterForm?
is it forms.py?

Answer (score 0):

in views.py add this 
from .forms import RegisterForm